# How do I specify my migrations folder with typeorm and NestJS 10?

Tags: nestjs, migration, entity, typeorm

I'm using NestJS 10 and TypeORM 0.3.17.  I want to generate a migration from my entity, stored in src/entities/user.entity.ts, which is

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;
}
```

I have this in package.json ...

```
"migration:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run -- -d ./src/config/typeorm.ts",
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- -d ./src/config/typeorm.ts migration:generate ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name",
"migration:create": "npm run typeorm -- migration:create ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name",
"migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- -d ./src/config/typeorm.ts migration:revert"
```

but when I run the command to generate the migration my migraitons folder, I get this error

```
$ npx typeorm migration:create -o UserData -d src/migrations
typeorm migration:create <path>

Creates a new migration file.

Options:
  -h, --help       Show help                                           [boolean]
  -o, --outputJs   Generate a migration file on Javascript instead of Typescript
                                                      [boolean] [default: false]
  -t, --timestamp  Custom timestamp for the migration name
                                                       [number] [default: false]
  -v, --version    Show version number                                 [boolean]

Unknown argument: d
```

How can I create my migration for my User entity in the right folder?

Comment: try to replace `typeorm:cli` instead of typeorm in your package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case will add typeorm like this below:

```
    "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -d src/config/typeorm.ts",
```

your migration:generate line will be:

```
    "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name",
```

and command will be:

```
npm run migration:generate --name=your_migration_name
```